# magento get product using proudct id

Tags: magento, attributes, product

I am trying to get feature product of magento, I am getting all product ids properly in each variables, but its not working inside the loop and shows repeated product.

here is my code

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();   
$categoryId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id', false);
$resource = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$read = $resource->getConnection('catalog_read');
$categoryProductTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog/category_product');
//$productEntityIntTable = $resource->getTableName('catalog/product_entity_int'); // doesn't work :(
$productEntityIntTable = (string)Mage::getConfig()->getTablePrefix() . 'catalog_product_entity_int';
$eavAttributeTable = $resource->getTableName('eav/attribute');

$select = $read->select()
    ->from(array('cp'=>$categoryProductTable))
    ->join(array('pei'=>$productEntityIntTable), 'pei.entity_id=cp.product_id', array())
    ->joinNatural(array('ea'=>$eavAttributeTable))
    ->where('pei.value=1')
    ->where('ea.attribute_code="featured"');            

$_product = $read->fetchAll($select);
$total_product= count($_product);
```

when i print_r($_product) it shows multiple id of product which are features so its correct

but inside for loop when i try to get product name using id it shows repeated Product names,here is the code

```
$obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
for($cp=0;$cp <= $total_product; $cp++):
    $_product= $obj->load($_product[$cp]['product_id']);
    echo $_product->getName();
endfor;
```

Comment: hi thanks for reply i tried that but now it shows only one product, i have 18 product in count($_product) value.also it shows all id when i print_r($_product).

Comment: you did a mistake ...you are reassigning the $_product array so it is giving you only one product so please change the $_product to $_productnew in for loop...check my code

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
for($cp=0;$cp <= $total_product; $cp++):
 $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $_productnew= $obj->load($_product[$cp]['product_id']);
echo $_productnew->getName();
endfor;
```

Comment: @vishal: Its happen sometime :)

Answer (score 0):

Put $obj inside for loop like below,

```
for($cp=0;$cp <= $total_product; $cp++):
 $obj = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
 $_product= $obj->load($_product[$cp]['product_id']);
 echo $_product->getName();

endfor;
```